# Alfresco cloud modify file https method

Tags: alfresco

I use alfresco cloud.

I can authentificate, get my access_token, and access to a file by having a get request:

[GET] https://api.alfresco.com/mycompany.com/public/cmis/versions/1.0/atom/content?id=id_of_my_file&access_token=my_access_token

Now I want to update the content of the file. The doc say to use PUT request. Is what I did :

[PUT] https://api.alfresco.com/mycompany.com/public/cmis/versions/1.0/atom/content?id=id_of_my_file&access_token=my_access_token

But I have this error :

{
  "error":"invalid_request",
  "error_description":"Missing access token"
}

Comment: Are you sure you don't need to send the access token in something other than the URL parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Gagravarr says, try putting your access token in the authorization field of the HTTP request header, like this:
Bearer [your access token]

See "Using the Access Token" in the [API documentation PDF](http://www.alfresco.com/cmis/browser?id=workspace://SpacesStore/b09d212a-00c6-4ec3-9764-0eca67bb8529).

Comment: It works with firefox extension RESTClient, but when I try to do it in jQuery (by settings header with beforeSend and setRequestHeader), still 403 forbidden. Any idea ?